# Create function for dataframe to parquet creation

Tags: python, function, dataframe, pyspark

How to create a function for dataframe to parquet creation?

The syntax for dataframe to parquet file creation is something like - (pyspark)

df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("file_name.parquet")

To create a function for this, I am trying in this way :

```
    def parquet_create(df_name,file_name):
        df_name.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(file_name+".parquet")
    return
```

But when I run with parquet_create("abc","eee") ... It fails with

```
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

So, I initalized an empty dataframe to above, Are there any cleaner way to achieve the same?

```
    def parquet_create(df_name,file_name):
       df_name = sqlContext.read.json("my_empty_file.parquet")
       df_name = df_name.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(file_name+".parquet")
       return
```

How to do it if dataframe initalized out of the function??

Comment: Looks like you're passing in the name of a dataframe, and not the object itself

Comment: Yea i want to pass the name of the dataframe and use the above function whenever I want to create a parquet

Comment: From a dataframe that already exists, or one that you will make later? It seems to me that you don't need to make an empty parquet file, and if you already have a filled dataframe there's no reason not to just pass in the dataframe object itself

Comment: If I am initalizing the df inside, my code works, but how to achieve it if df is initalized outside function?

Comment: I'll take a stab at an answer, we can edit until we get something that seems right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as it stands is trying to create a parquet file from a dataframe called `df_name` which is passed as an argument. What it receives instead of a dataframe is a string, so it fails. The ideal scenario here is that instead of passing in the string name of a dataframe, you pass in the object, like so:

```
df = ... # define a dataframe
filename = ... # some filename
parquet_create(df, filename)
```

It sounds like that's not an option for you for some reason, so there are a couple of workarounds. You can create a dictionary relating string dataframe names to dataframe objects like this:

```
df = ... # define a dataframe
df2 = ... # define another dataframe
filename = ... # some filename
name_map = {'df': df, 'df2': df2}
parquet_create('df', filename)
```

and define `parquet_create` like this:

```
def parquet_create(df_name, file_name):
    name_map[df_name].write.mode('overwrite').parquet(file_name+".parquet")
```

You will have to ensure that `name_map` is defined in the scope of `parquet_create`.

The only other option I can think of is using `eval`:

```
df = ... # define a dataframe
filename = ... # some filename
parquet_create(df, filename)

def parquet_create(df_name, file_name):
    eval(df_name).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(file_name+".parquet")
```

Note that you will also have to make sure that df is in the scope of parquet_create for this solution as well.

Both of these are really ugly solutions in my mind, and I honestly can't think of a reason not to just pass in the dataframe object itself, but there you go.